# Understanding SystemParametersInfo SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi, focus

My App needs to get the focus when it get's called by an external tool (via an API), i know that the default is, that it should just flash in the Taskbar, but in this case this is absolutely not the behaviour that i want. In this case i try to get the focus by "this.Activate()" (C#).

This is where the ForeGroundLockTimeOut comes into play.
However, I got a little problem understanding the SystemParameterInfo SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT.

I know that it's used to set the ForeGroundLockTimeOut which defines how long your app has to wait until it gets the focus it requested.

(for further information the variable "val" is an IntPtr that is set to 0)

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT,0,val,SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE + SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

this one will change the Registry key that that handles the timeout (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\ForeGroundLockTimout)
Since this will change the behaviour of all apps, it's really the last resort to use.

Now i thought what if i don't update the registry key. So i tried this:

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT, 0, val, 0);
```

However it doesn't change the behavior of my app in any way, but

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT,0,val,SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
```

does.

What i do not understand is why this only works for my app, which is absolutely what i want, but i do not understandit .Why do i have to broadcast a change, that only works for my app, when there has been no change made to any registry key or whatsoever, and why does this work only for my app.

Note: If you want to test this behavior, test it when Visual Studio is not running, while it's running (even if this Solution is not loaded) it changes the behavior of the App into getting focus in any case.

Comment: *it changes the behavior of the App into getting focus in any case.* Did you even [read the fine manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx)? *The system restricts which processes can set the foreground window. A process can set the foreground window only if one of the following conditions is true: ... The foreground process is being debugged.* What you're trying to do reminds me of [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx).

Comment: Also reminds me of [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/20/9435239.aspx).

Comment: yea i read it, and no i do not try to make my window topmost, it's running in the background for most of the time, i want it to get the focus when it's called via an api (will add that to the question) but it should not be topmost even while it has the focus.

Comment: And yea it reminds of [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/20/9435239.aspx), but i do want to steal the focus and not let the other app give it to me since i'm not always able to modify the code of the external tool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a per-app setting, it is a global system setting. There's no way to set it for just your application, so when you call `SystemParametersInfo` with 0 for the last parameter, nothing happens.

On the other hand, when you use `SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE`, the new setting gets broadcast in the form of a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message. (Which is why manually editing the registry is the wrong thing to do; always call the documented API.)

Aside from that, this code is wrong:

```
SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE + SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE
```

To concatenate two flags, you must use the boolean OR operator (`|`), not the addition operator (`+`). In this particular case, because `0x1 + 0x2` and `0x1 | 0x2` are both equal to 3, it seems to work, but that's just an accident.

The real solution to this problem needs not involve manipulating global settings (because you surely don't want to do that on client machines, even if you're OK with it on your own). You need to work *with* the system, rather than trying to work against it. In the system's model, the process that currently has the focus is the one with the privilege of setting/changing the focus. So there are basically three options:

1. Just have the external tool call `SetForegroundWindow` itself and pass your application's window as the parameter. This altogether avoids your app having to activate itself.
2. Use the [`AllowSetForegroundWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632668.aspx) function to delegate the external tool's foreground-window-setting privileges to your application.  It should call this function, passing the ID of your app's process as the parameter. That way, when your app calls `SetForegroundWindow`, it will work as expected.
3. Depending on how your tool and application are designed, you could just have the external tool *launch* the application. Like [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539.aspx) says, if a process is launched by the foreground process, it is allowed to set the foreground window.

Comment: Hm i'm not sure if this is entirely correct. when i call it with SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE only the behavior of my app changes, not of others

Comment: And considering your real solution, the problem here is that i'm not necessarily able to alter the code of the external tool

Comment: That's because only your app knows about the behavior. None of the other apps were notified. Try restarting, logging off and back on, or even relaunching one of the apps. If you can't alter the external tool, you're out of luck. How does it know how to interact with your app?

Comment: it's interacting via an api, but restarting the other apps doesn't do any difference, they still behave "normal" with flashing in the taskbar, restart and relog doesn't change anything, too, since i did not modify the registry key. (on the second and third attempt)

Comment: Okay, then the registry key is cached and they're retrieving it from the cache. You have to restart. Editing the registry is *not* the way to make these changes.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, it seems like you are right... the registry key is being cached and restarting the other apps leads to the same behavior. And I agree with you that editing the registry key is not the way to do this, I thought like this it might be possible to get this behavior only for my app. Seems like I have to search for another Solution.

Answer (score 0):

SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE--Writes the new system-wide parameter setting to the user profile.
SPIF_SENDCHANGE--Broadcasts the WM_SETTINGCHANGE message after updating the user profile.